# Correct way of filtering two observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

My task was to get observable list based on two other lists. Here's the code that works, but I wonder if it is OK (from performance prospective as well):

```
get availableCodeValueLanguages$(): Observable<Common.Lookup<string>[]> {
    return this.languageCodesLookupData$.pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.languageData$),
      map(([lookupLanguages, codeValues]) => {
        const codeValueLanguageCodes = codeValues.map(codeValue => codeValue.language.id);
        return lookupLanguages.filter(lookupLanguage =>
          !codeValueLanguageCodes.includes(lookupLanguage.id));
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        return of([]);
      })
    )
  }
```

**languageData$** contains data for a *grid*. It is a list of complex properties *CodeValue*, each of such includes distinct *Language*. **languageCodesLookupData$** is a complete list of all available *language*s. **availableCodeValueLanguages$** needs to include the *language*s for *dropdownlist*, it needs to be possible to add only one *Language* per *CodeValue* on a *form*.

**languageCodesLookupData$** is loaded on *Component Init* (highly unlikely it's gonna change during working with a page). Correspondingly, **languageData$** is changed once we add a new entry to the *CodeValue* list in the *form*.

Comment: Looks okay, you can also use `combileLatest` operator as well to achieve this.

Comment: You don't need to use a `get`, you can just define as `availableCodeValueLanguages$ = this.languageCodesLookupData$.pipe(...)`

Comment: @bizzybob - is it better from performance point of view or just shorter? :)

Comment: just shorter... no performance benefit :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine from a performance perspective, using `withLatestFrom` is a typical way to combine streams.

However...

> languageCodesLookupData$ is loaded on Component Init (highly unlikely it's gonna change during working with a page)

Using `withLatestFrom` will only emit when the source observable emits.

> languageData$ is changed once we add a new entry to the CodeValue list in the form.

So, I'm assuming you'd want `availableCodeValueLanguages$` when this happens.
If that's the case, you should use `combineLatest`:

```
availableCodeValueLanguages$ = combineLatest(
  this.languageCodesLookupData$,
  this.languageData$
).pipe(
  map(([lookupLanguages, codeValues]) => {
    const codeValueLanguageCodes = codeValues.map(codeValue => codeValue.language.id);
    return lookupLanguages.filter(lookupLanguage =>
      !codeValueLanguageCodes.includes(lookupLanguage.id));
  }),
  catchError(error => {
    return of([]);
  })
);
```

You could define `codeValueLanguageCodes` as its own observable if you wanted.

```
codeIds$ = this.languageData$.pipe(
    map(codeValue => codeValue.language.id)
);

availableCodeValueLanguages$ = combineLatest(
  this.languageCodesLookupData$,
  this.codeIds$
).pipe(
  map(([languages, codeIds]) => languages.filter(
    language => !codeIds.includes(language.id));
  ),
  catchError(error => {
    return of([]);
  })
);
```

Comment: I have another implementation in a different way, using my custom `export class ExcludeIdsFilterPipe implements PipeTransform` (its code is simple and not shown for bravity) like that: `licencesLookupData$ | async | excludeIdsFilter: { excludeIds: nonAvailableModuleLicenceIds, isNumeric: true }` and `excludeIds` is derived as `this.store.select(state => state.ModuleLicencesState).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe((state: ModuleLicences.State)` in component constructor. Could you please tell if it is also OK?

Comment: I think performance could be fine doing that.  My preference would be to put the logic into the controller instead of a pipe.  Pipes are nice because they can perform logic in a clean way which you can easily read in your template.  But if you need to pass objects to the pipe, it becomes messy and loses the readability.  So, I think it's easier to do the transformation logic on your observable stream in the controller.